# Sharepoint JSOM, reusable function to get list items, only working for 1 list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, getlist

I am currently working on a custom intranet that will have at least 5 jsom calls needing to be made on it to different lists.

I have managed to create a function that successfully takes in the variables and returns the information, but when trying to do two of them I seem to get a conflict and it fails, only showing the second get request.

Here is the error that appears when trying to reuse the function.

error message
[image: error message]

I have have created similar functions for use with the REST API but in this we need to use Publishing Images, so JSOM is required.

Can you help me find what is wrong with my approach below please :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){retrieveListItems(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,
"Essential Links",drawEssentialLinks,"<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Order0' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>")},
"sp.js");

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){retrieveListItems(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,
"Announcements",drawAnnouncements,"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='DisplayAnnouncement'/><Value Type='Choice'>Yes</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef
 Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>")},
"sp.js");

});

function retrieveListItems(siteUrl,
listTitle, sucessFunction,Query) {

var clientContext =
new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

var oList =
clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);


var camlQuery =
new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml(Query);

this.collListItem =
oList.getItems(camlQuery);


clientContext.load(collListItem);


clientContext.executeQueryAsync(sucessFunction,onQueryFailed);


}

function onQueryFailed(sender,
args) {

console.log(args);

}

function drawEssentialLinks(sender,
args) {

var listItems =
'';

var listItemEnumerator =
collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

var oListItem =
listItemEnumerator.get_current();

var link =
oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink");

if(link ==
null || link ==
"" || link ==
undefined){

link = "#";

}else{

link = oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink").get_url();

}

if(!isNaN(oListItem.get_item("Order0"))){

if(oListItem.get_item("OpenLinkInNewTab") ==
"Yes"){

listItems += 
"<li><a href='"+link+"' target='_blank'>"+oListItem.get_item('Image')+"<span>"+oListItem.get_item("Title")+"</span></a></li>"

}else{

listItems += 
"<li><a href='"+link+"'>"+oListItem.get_item('Image')+"<span>"+oListItem.get_item("Title")+"</span></a></li>"

}


}

}

$("#essential-links ul").html(listItems);

}

function drawAnnouncements(sender,
args){

var listItems =
'';

var announcments =
0;

var listItemEnumerator =
collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

var oListItem =
listItemEnumerator.get_current();

var link =
oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink");

if(link ==
null || link ==
"" || link ==
undefined){

link = "#";

}else{

link = oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink").get_url();

}

listItems += 
"<li><div class='wrapper'>"+oListItem.get_item('Image')+" <div class='announcement-text'><p>"+oListItem.get_item("Title")+"</p><p><a
 href='"+link+"'>More Info...</a></p></div></div></li>"

}

$("#announcements ul").html(listItems);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have update your with deffered and promise as jsom is asynchronous

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getMultipleListitems(),"sp.js");
});

function getMultipleListitems(){
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var querystr1 = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Order0' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
    var querystr2 = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='DisplayAnnouncement'/><Value Type='Choice'>Yes</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>"

    retrieveListItems(siteUrl,"Essential Links",querystr1).done(
        function (getEnuCollection){drawEssentialLinks(getEnuCollection);},function (getEnuCollection){console.log('fail in first call');});

    retrieveListItems(siteUrl,"Announcements",drawAnnouncements,querystr2).done(
        function (getEnuCollection){drawAnnouncements(getEnuCollection);},function (getEnuCollection){console.log('fail in second call');});           

}  


function retrieveListItems(siteUrl,listTitle,Query) {  

    //Declare your deferred object here  
    var deferred=$.Deferred();  
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);        
    var olist = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);  
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(Query);
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);  
    clientContext.load(collListItem);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),  
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.failure)  
    );  
    //Return your Promise Object  
    return deferred.promise();  
}; 

function success(sender, args) {            
    //Resolve your object here  
    deferred.resolve(ocamlItems.getEnumerator());            
}  

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log(args);  
    //Reject your object here  
    deferred.reject(ocamlItems.getEnumerator());  
}  


function drawEssentialLinks(getEnuCollection) {
    var listItemEnumerator = getEnuCollection;

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var oListItem =listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var link =oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink");
        if(link){
            link = oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink").get_url();
        }else{
            link = "#";
        }           

        if(!isNaN(oListItem.get_item("Order0"))){

            if(oListItem.get_item("OpenLinkInNewTab") =="Yes"){
                listItems += "<li><a href='"+link+"' target='_blank'>"+oListItem.get_item('Image')+"<span>"+oListItem.get_item("Title")+"</span></a></li>"
            }else{
                listItems += "<li><a href='"+link+"'>"+oListItem.get_item('Image')+"<span>"+oListItem.get_item("Title")+"</span></a></li>"
            }
        }
    }
    $("#essential-links ul").html(listItems);
}

function drawAnnouncements(getEnuCollection){      

    var announcments =0;

    var listItemEnumerator =getEnuCollection;

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem =listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var link =oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink");

        if(link){
            link = oListItem.get_item("Hyperlink").get_url();
        }else{
            link = "#";
        }            

        listItems += "<li><div class='wrapper'>" + oListItem.get_item('Image') + " <div class='announcement-text'><p>" + oListItem.get_item("Title") + "</p><p><a href='" + link + "'>More Info...</a></p></div></div></li>";
    }
    $("#announcements ul").html(listItems);
}
```

Let me know if any issue. [And can refer here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-implement-deferred-and-promise-object-in-javascript-asynchronous/) for asynchronous call